# ios7 blank screen from framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a framework that creates some views, the app that uses the framework calls a method from it and pass in the current view controller, the framework then calls presentModalViewController to display a view.

It was working just fine with iOS 6.1 SDK but when I updated to Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK I don't see the modal view anymore, instead all I get is a blank screen.

**EDIT**

Heres some code:

The Framework is called "testityi"

testityi.m

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@implementation testitiy

- (NSString*) sayHi : (NSString*) name {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
}

- (void) displayView:(UIViewController *)parentController {
    TestViewController* controller = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [parentController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

TestViewController is simply a view with a label that says "View from framework"

The framework itself works fine, calling sayHi method works just fine.

The third party app has a view with a label and a button which calls sayHi method and then displayView method, heres the view controller code:

MainViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    testitiy* framework = [[testitiy alloc] init];
    NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Calling sayHi method on framework...\n     result: %@", [framework sayHi:@"John"]];
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"sayHi method call"     message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, show me the view" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        testitiy* framework = [[testitiy alloc] init];
        [framework displayView:self];
    }
}
```

The alert button action is also working correctly, I added a NSLog before and its working.

**After clicking the alert button a view is presented but instead of containing the label "View from framework" I get a blank screen.**

You can see the code on [Github](https://github.com/sebastianteres/iosframeworktest)

**EDIT 2**

I got it... I wasn't calling initWithBundle on the ViewController from the framework, I added the a custom init method that calls:

framework: TestViewController.m

```
+ (NSBundle *)frameworkBundle {
    static NSBundle* frameworkBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        NSString* mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString* frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testity.bundle"];
        frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
    });
    return frameworkBundle;
}

- (id) initWithFramework {
    NSBundle* bundle = [[self class] frameworkBundle];
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle: bundle];
    return self;
}
```

And changed testitiy.m

```
- (void) displayView:(UIViewController *)parentController {
    TestViewController* controller = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithFramework];
    [parentController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[parentController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

And now its working...

I hope this helps someone else but I'm guessing it was a stupid mistake of mine.
Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for your time!

Comment: without some code it's kind of hard to tell.

Comment: `presentModalViewController:` is deprecated. See if calling the proper `presentViewController:animated:completion:` works.

Comment: A rushed into a meeting and said: "ow, aeh, sorry... but something, somehow seemed to have stopped working" .... B replied: "you should find someone to fix it!"

Comment: Thanks for the comments, presentViewController:animated:completion: brings the same result

Comment: I'll put together some code for you to look at ASAP

Comment: Ok I created a test and uploaded the code to github, please see my EDIT... thanks!

Comment: I don't have any intent to look at the project ASAP, but you might want to check yourself if the resource files of the framework are available to the application.

Comment: sorry I meant I would put the code together ASAP, not that you would look at it ASAP (sorry about my english)... Thanks for the hint, I imported the bundle from the framework, which contains the nib file for the view I'm trying to get, but I'm not sure if I need to do something more than just importing it, I'll take a look... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while I finally understand the issue:

When using a custom framework, all resources like images and NIB files have to be manually included in the third-party app so that it has access to those files.

My problem was that I was including the resources (stored in a bundle) into the third-party app but the framework was trying to display the View based on its own resources, which the app couldn't access, for that reason I was getting a blank screen.

I just needed to tell the framework to use the included bundle into the third-party app to display that View (using the initWithNibName: Bundle method).

See EDIT 2 in the question to see the code that solved my problem.

Hope this helps someone. :-)

Comment: How to create xibs and images in bundle? any ref.s?